# How to find POST friendships/create limit with tweepy in python 3?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using tweepy to follow users on twitter but I'm hitting the 400 daily limit, I want to implement checks so this doesn't happen, I am using the following code:

```
limits = api.rate_limit_status()
```

This grabs some limits but doesn't seem to include any post POST endpoint limits only GET endpoints. My question is how can I access POST endpoint limits using tweepy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the API referenced by [api.rate_limit_status()](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/rate-limit-status/api-reference/get-application-rate_limit_status) doesn't include POST endpoints. I would suggest wrapping your API calls in a try catch like below

```
# In this example, the handler is time.sleep(15 * 60),
# but you can of course handle it in any way you want.

def limit_handled(cursor):
    while True:
        try:
            yield cursor.next()
        except tweepy.RateLimitError:
            time.sleep(15 * 60)

for follower in limit_handled(tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items()):
    if follower.friends_count < 300:
        print(follower.screen_name)
```

The other option is to manually keep track of your API calls with the limits described [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits). You can use another python module called [ratelimit](https://pypi.org/project/ratelimit/) for this

```
pip install ratelimit
```

```
# example.py:
from ratelimit import limits

import requests

THREE_HOURS = 3*60*60
FRIENDSHIP_POST_API_LIMIT = 300

@limits(calls=FRIENDSHIP_POST_API_LIMIT, period=THREE_HOURS)
def create_friendship(user_id):
    return api.create_friendship(user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like the best way to do it!